# How to Convert image file to binary format

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to convert any image file from my system to binary format by giving the path of the image from the system. After converting I want to store the converted binary format in a folder. How can i do it? It should be a Windows Form application.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary format" exactly? Almost all image formats are binary formats rather than text...

Comment: i think he just want to convert it into 0 and 1  like 010010111100101010000111001...etc

Comment: @AravindSrinivas: Yes, I can see that's what you think he wants - but I'm really not so sure at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really just trying to store a file in a database, you don't need to worry about it being an image at all. The image file will already be in a "binary format" - you just need to store the file data. There may well be ways of doing this in a streaming way, but unless the files are huge it's probably just simpler to load them into byte arrays:

```
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
```

Then use `image` as the parameter value in a parameterized SQL statement, e.g.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Foo (Path, ImageData) VALUES (@Path, @ImageData");
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = imagePath;
        command.Parameters.Add("@ImageData", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imageData;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: After the image are stored in a folder i want to retrieve it through database by giving the path of the folder in db.Is this possible?

Comment: @Jameskumar: I don't really follow what you're saying - you'd be storing it in the *database*, surely. But yes, once it's in the database, you should be able to retrieve it... if you're having trouble with that, I suggest you post a new question to show what you've tried and what the problem is.

Comment: @Jameskumar databases contain neither paths nor folders, so no, either you store your image data on disk and put the path in the DB, or you have to fetch (e.g. `SELECT` in SQL) it back from the DB when loading.